# App Crashing on Android Version 6.0 only [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800d3]

Tags: java, android

Thou someone told me it is not working also on version 4. but i did a test run on Android 6.0 and after installation and login app crashed. You can find the app on [Play Store [CITY KRUIZ]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp)

Here are all my log error code:

```
09-16 13:31:40.410 11839-11839/com.swaq.joemayami.riderapp E/UncaughtException: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800d3
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1683)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:491)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:118)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:429)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6508)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6541)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5484)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5750)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1196)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5606)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2742)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16961)
```

Comment: can you post the adapter

Comment: I am still new to android development pardon me, what is the adapter and where i can i get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `drawable` folder for necessary images/resources. Seems you’ve placed the images/resources in `drawable-v21` folder or something similar.

Comment: can i delete that folder out of the project

Comment: Move the resources to drawable folder and remove drawable-v21 folder.